# Is there a way to set a background color on an `image::ImageBuffer`?

Tags: rust

Using the [image](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/index.html) crate, I can create an `ImageBuffer` then put a pixel and save it:

```
let mut img = ImageBuffer::new(100, 100);
img.put_pixel(50, 50);

let ref mut fout = File::create(&Path::new("test.png")).unwrap();
let _ = ImageRgb8(img).save(fout, PNG);
```

I want to set a background color (default is black). I could iterate on pixels and put a pixel of the same color on each, but I'm not sure it's the best way (it seems overkill). I think I missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you continue reading the documentation, you will find [`ImageBuffer::from_pixel`](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html#method.from_pixel):

> ```
> fn from_pixel(width: u32,
>               height: u32,
>               pixel: P)
>               -> ImageBuffer<P, Vec<P::Subpixel>>
> ```
>
> Constructs a new `ImageBuffer` by copying a pixel

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `from_pixel` and `from_fn` methods to form a buffer with a custom background.

Here's an example from a project of mine where I drop a shadow on the background.

```
enum Grace {
    /// How much "grace" time have passed, in percents.
    Good (f32),
    Picked,
    Delayed,
    Closed,
    /// Closed by GM without player making a choice.
    Miss}

impl Grace {
    fn from_time (opened: i64, now: i64) -> Grace {
        let delta = now - (opened + 7200);  // First two hours are "free".
        if delta <= 0 {return Grace::Good (0.0)}
        let percent = (delta * 100) as f32 / time::Duration::hours (24) .num_seconds() as f32;
        if percent <= 100.0 {Grace::Good (percent)} else {Grace::Delayed}}}

let mut ib = ImageBuffer::from_fn (600, 24, |x, y| Rgba (match grace {
    Grace::Picked | Grace::Closed => [200, 200, 255, (255 * y / 24) as u8],
    Grace::Good (pc) => [pc as u8, (70 + (130 * x / 600)) as u8, 0, (255 * y / 24) as u8],
    Grace::Delayed => [(70 + (130 * x / 600)) as u8, (70 + (130 * x / 600)) as u8, 0, (255 * y / 24) as u8],
    Grace::Miss => [(70 + (130 * x / 600)) as u8, 0, 0, (255 * y / 24) as u8]}));
```